# Find all directory sizes in a folder

Tags: cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

I have a folder structure over a network drive with an unknown number of folders and sub folders in it. I am looking for a way to output a list of all folder and sub folders, most importantly, their individual sizes, and to include which sub folders are in which other folders. I do not want any actual files, just folders and their total sizes.
Current line I am working with is:

```
dir "N:\Folder Name" /o/s | Findstr/r " Directory | Bytes" >> C:\Temp\List.txt
```

(Folder name has a space in it, if that matters)
--Updated Post--

Comment: `dir /S /O "N:\Folder Name" | findstr /R /C:" Directory of " /C:" bytes$" > "C:\Temp\List.txt"`? Note that `dir` just sums up the sizes of the immediate child files; if you want to add also the sizes of files in their sub-directories, `dir` cannot be used. By the way, a directory actually has got no size...

Comment: @aschipfl, `dir /s | findstr /r /c:"^ " /c:"\\\\"` is a safer non locale dependant alternative. And directories can have size, test `for /d %a in ("c:\windows\*") do @echo %a %~za`

Comment: Very clever, @MCND! I don't know what the `~z` sizes of a directory represent (do you?), but I guess that's not what the OP wants...

Comment: @aschipfl, size of a folder/directory is the space on disk (out of the MFT) used to store the folder/directory information (it should be n*cluster size).

Comment: MCND, tired your modification and it's outputting all the sub folders like I wanted, which is very nice, but not displaying any sizes.

Comment: `for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%ProgramFiles%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.` from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/how-do-i-delete-the-another-user-to-free-up-hard/1d2ec7c1-4390-41f7-8e2e-020473fafeae

Comment: Ended up using aschipfl's solution with MCND's modification and a bit of formatting afterward. Which worked good enough. No way to mark it as correct.

Comment: @MCND 's comment should be its own answer because... it is the answer